# Built-in way to convert Integer to Ordinal String

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

Is there a built-in way to convert an integer into its ordinal string representation (as per [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_(linguistics))). That is, something akin to

```
{1 -> "1st", 2 -> "2nd", (*etc...*)}
```

or

```
{1 -> "First", 2 -> "Second", (*etc...*)}
```

Comment: I have now migrated my answer to this post (see [below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190568/764)). In short:  As of Version 10 there is `IntegerName` but it needs to be tweaked to give what you/we want.

Comment: Consider `ResourceFunction["OrdinalNumberString"]` from the [Wolfram Resource Library](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OrdinalNumberString).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The coolest way is to check the answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/outputting-ordinal-numbers-1st-2nd-3rd) by David Carraher. I am shamelessly stealing his code here to write a function that gives you rules for up to `maxNumber`:

```
ordinalRule[maxNumber_Integer] /; maxNumber > 0 := 
  Block[{p},
    Thread[
      Function[{x}, 
        x -> StringSplit[SpokenString[p[[#]]]][[2]] &[x] // Quiet] /@ Range[maxNumber]
  ]];
```

For example:

```
ordinalRule[100]

(*out*){1 -> "1st", 2 -> "2nd", 3 -> "3rd", 4 -> "4th", 5 -> "5th", 
 6 -> "6th", 7 -> "7th", 8 -> "8th", 9 -> "9th", 10 -> "10th", 
 11 -> "11th", 12 -> "12th", 13 -> "13th", 14 -> "14th", 15 -> "15th",
  16 -> "16th", 17 -> "17th", 18 -> "18th", 19 -> "19th", 
 20 -> "20th", 21 -> "21st", 22 -> "22nd", 23 -> "23rd", 24 -> "24th",
  25 -> "25th", 26 -> "26th", 27 -> "27th", 28 -> "28th", 
 29 -> "29th", 30 -> "30th", 31 -> "31st", 32 -> "32nd", 33 -> "33rd",
  34 -> "34th", 35 -> "35th", 36 -> "36th", 37 -> "37th", 
 38 -> "38th", 39 -> "39th", 40 -> "40th", 41 -> "41st", 42 -> "42nd",
  43 -> "43rd", 44 -> "44th", 45 -> "45th", 46 -> "46th", 
 47 -> "47th", 48 -> "48th", 49 -> "49th", 50 -> "50th", 51 -> "51st",
  52 -> "52nd", 53 -> "53rd", 54 -> "54th", 55 -> "55th", 
 56 -> "56th", 57 -> "57th", 58 -> "58th", 59 -> "59th", 60 -> "60th",
  61 -> "61st", 62 -> "62nd", 63 -> "63rd", 64 -> "64th", 
 65 -> "65th", 66 -> "66th", 67 -> "67th", 68 -> "68th", 69 -> "69th",
  70 -> "70th", 71 -> "71st", 72 -> "72nd", 73 -> "73rd", 
 74 -> "74th", 75 -> "75th", 76 -> "76th", 77 -> "77th", 78 -> "78th",
  79 -> "79th", 80 -> "80th", 81 -> "81st", 82 -> "82nd", 
 83 -> "83rd", 84 -> "84th", 85 -> "85th", 86 -> "86th", 87 -> "87th",
  88 -> "88th", 89 -> "89th", 90 -> "90th", 91 -> "91st", 
 92 -> "92nd", 93 -> "93rd", 94 -> "94th", 95 -> "95th", 96 -> "96th",
  97 -> "97th", 98 -> "98th", 99 -> "99th", 100 -> "100th"}
```

I don't know whether this counts as built-in though.

**----EDIT----**

From @Wreach's comment: there is an undocumented built-in (that `SpokenString` calls when dealing with numbers to ordinals) that does exactly that:

```
Speak["stackexchange"];
SpokenStringDump`SpeakOrdinal[121]
(*out*) 121st
```

In v10 I need to call `Speak` before the relevant function auto-loads.

Comment: Might not be completely builtin, but still very neat. Nice find!

Comment: +1 It uses an undocumented internal function like this: ``SpokenStringDump`SpeakOrdinal[1]`` returning `"1st"`.  You might have to reference the symbol `Speak` first to make sure that the package is auto-loaded.

Answer (score 10):

I noticed only afterwards that you were asking for a built-in method. I'm not certain if you would actually want to rely on an undocumented feature instead of writing your own, since it's not hard.

This requires v10 for `StringTemplate`. It could be replaced with something else, of course...

```
Range[120] /.
 { tens_Integer /; Floor[Mod[tens, 100], 10] == 10 :> StringTemplate["`1`th"][tens],
   firsts_Integer /; Mod[firsts, 10] == 1 :> StringTemplate["`1`st"][firsts],
   seconds_Integer /; Mod[seconds, 10] == 2 :> StringTemplate["`1`nd"][seconds],
   thirds_Integer /; Mod[thirds, 10] == 3 :> StringTemplate["`1`rd"][thirds],
   rest_Integer :> StringTemplate["`1`th"][rest] }

(* { "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th",
     "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th",
     "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th",
     "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st", "32nd", "33rd",
     "34th", "35th", "36th", "37th", "38th", "39th", "40th", "41st",
     "42nd", "43rd", "44th", "45th", "46th", "47th", "48th", "49th",
     "50th", "51st", "52nd", "53rd", "54th", "55th", "56th", "57th",
     "58th", "59th", "60th", "61st", "62nd", "63rd", "64th", "65th",
     "66th", "67th", "68th", "69th", "70th", "71st", "72nd", "73rd",
     "74th", "75th", "76th", "77th", "78th", "79th", "80th", "81st",
     "82nd", "83rd", "84th", "85th", "86th", "87th", "88th", "89th",
     "90th", "91st", "92nd", "93rd", "94th", "95th", "96th", "97th",
     "98th", "99th", "100th", "101st", "102nd", "103rd", "104th", 
     "105th", "106th", "107th", "108th", "109th", "110th", "111th",
     "112th", "113th", "114th", "115th", "116th", "117th", "118th",
     "119th", "120th" } *)
```

Answer (score 6):

A brute force but very simple approach (no undocumented functions needed) that I think will work with any version of *Mathematica*.

```
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 100] == 11] := generalRule[n]
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 100] == 12] := generalRule[n]
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 100] == 13] := generalRule[n]
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 10] == 1] = specialRule1[n];
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 10] == 2] = specialRule2[n];
ordinalRule[n_Integer /; Mod[n, 10] == 3] = specialRule3[n];
ordinalRule[n_Integer] = generalRule[n];
specialRule1[n_] := n -> (ToString[n] <> "st")
specialRule2[n_] := n -> (ToString[n] <> "nd")
specialRule3[n_] := n -> (ToString[n] <> "rd")
generalRule[n_] := n -> (ToString[n] <> "th")

ordinalRule /@ Range @ 130
```

> ```
> {1 -> "1st", 2 -> "2nd", 3 -> "3rd", 4 -> "4th", 5 -> "5th", 
>  6 -> "6th", 7 -> "7th", 8 -> "8th", 9 -> "9th", 10 -> "10th", 
>  11 -> "11th", 12 -> "12th", 13 -> "13th", 14 -> "14th", 15 -> "15th", 
>  16 -> "16th", 17 -> "17th", 18 -> "18th", 19 -> "19th", 20 -> "20th", 
>  21 -> "21st", 22 -> "22nd", 23 -> "23rd", 24 -> "24th", 25 -> "25th", 
>  26 -> "26th", 27 -> "27th", 28 -> "28th", 29 -> "29th", 30 -> "30th", 
>  31 -> "31st", 32 -> "32nd", 33 -> "33rd", 34 -> "34th", 35 -> "35th", 
>  36 -> "36th", 37 -> "37th", 38 -> "38th", 39 -> "39th", 40 -> "40th", 
>  ...
>  91 -> "91st", 92 -> "92nd", 93 -> "93rd", 94 -> "94th", 95 -> "95th", 
>  96 -> "96th", 97 -> "97th", 98 -> "98th", 99 -> "99th", 100 -> "100th", 
>  101 -> "101st", 102 -> "102nd", 103 -> "103rd", 104 -> "104th", 105 -> "105th", 
>  106 -> "106th", 107 -> "107th", 108 -> "108th", 109 -> "109th", 110 -> "110th", 
>  111 -> "111th", 112 -> "112th",  113 -> "113th", 114 -> "114th", 115 -> "115th", 
>  116 -> "116th", 117 -> "117th", 118 -> "118th", 119 -> "119th", 120 -> "120th", 
>  121 -> "121st", 122 -> "122nd", 123 -> "123rd", 124 -> "124th", 125 -> "125th", 
>  126 -> "126th", 127 -> "127th", 128 -> "128th", 129 -> "129th", 130 -> "130th"}
> ```

Comment: Ah, `<>` for string concatenation! I forgot it and just used templating. :)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:  As of Version 10 there is [`IntegerName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html), but it has to be slightly modified to be really helpful for ordinal numbers.

### **Building a converter function**

`IntegerName` allows to provide qualifiers and combinations of these. Unfortunately, using `"Ordinal"` will not give a correctly spelled result since there is no *"and"* as in *"one hundred and first"* (cf. [here](https://howtospell.co.uk/how-to-spell-ordinal-numbers)).

Furthermore, you cannot obtain a `"DigitsWords"`-like output (e.g. *"101st"* ) for ordinal numbers by doing `IntegerName[ 101, {"DigitsWords", "Ordinal" }]` or `IntegerName[ 101, {"Ordinal", "DigitsWords" } ]` even though the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html?q=IntegerName) looks like combining *qualifiers* for `IntegerName` in this way should be possible.

But tweaking `IntegerName` slightly within a custom build converter function will get us what we want:

```
IntegerNameOrdinal[ i_Integer ] := With[
    { 
       stringPatternTwoDigits = IntegerName[ Range[1, 99], "Ordinal"]
    }   
    ,
    IntegerName[ i, "Ordinal" ] // StringReplace[
      ( a__ /; StringFree[a, "-"] ) ~~ b:stringPatternTwoDigits :> a ~~ "and " ~~ b
    ]
]

IntegerNameOrdinal[ i_Integer, "DigitsWords" ] := Module[
    {
        strEnding = IntegerName[ i, "Ordinal" ] // StringTake[ # ,-2 ]&,
        strDigits = ToString @ i
    }
    ,
    strDigits ~~ strEnding
]

IntegerNameOrdinal[ i_Integer, ___ ] := IntegerNameOrdinal[ i ]
```

Now, we get:

```
IntegerNameOrdinal[ 2000232, "Words" ] (* or simply: IntegerNameOrdinal[ 2000232 ] *)
```

> "two million two hundred and thirty-second"

```
IntegerNameOrdinal[ #, "DigitsWords" ]& /@ Range[ 100 ]
```

> {"1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th",
>   "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", "17th", 
>   "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", "25th", 
>   "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st", "32nd", "33rd", 
>   "34th", "35th", "36th", "37th", "38th", "39th", "40th", "41st", 
>   "42nd", "43rd", "44th", "45th", "46th", "47th", "48th", "49th", 
>   "50th", "51st", "52nd", "53rd", "54th", "55th", "56th", "57th", 
>   "58th", "59th", "60th", "61st", "62nd", "63rd", "64th", "65th", 
>   "66th", "67th", "68th", "69th", "70th", "71st", "72nd", "73rd", 
>   "74th", "75th", "76th", "77th", "78th", "79th", "80th", "81st", 
>   "82nd", "83rd", "84th", "85th", "86th", "87th", "88th", "89th", 
>   "90th", "91st", "92nd", "93rd", "94th", "95th", "96th", "97th", 
>   "98th", "99th", "100th"}

Answer (score 4):

```
ordinalizeF = Module[{mod = Boole[!MemberQ[{11, 12}, Mod[Abs[#], 100]] ] Mod[Abs[#], 10]}, 
   With[{suffix = Switch[mod, 1, "st", 2, "nd", 3, "rd", _, "th"]}, Row[{ToString@#, suffix}]]] &;

ordinalizeF /@ {1, 2, 3, 11, -12, 21, 33, 5542}
(* {1st, 2nd, 3rd, 11th, -12th, 21st, 33rd, 5542nd} *)

Thread[# -> ordinalizeF /@ #] &@{1, 2, 3, 11, -12, 21, 33, 542}
(*{1 -> 1st, 2 -> 2nd, 3 -> 3rd, 11 -> 11th, -12 -> -12th, 21 -> 21st, 33 -> 33rd, 542-> 542nd} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IntegerName` function was upgraded in 2017 with `version 11.1` according to the [doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html).

So here is an implementation for ordinal numbers as requested in the OP.

---

For languages where gender affects grammatical units, example usage is as follows:

```
IntegerName[#, {"Italian", "Ordinal", "Feminine"}] & /@ Range[0, 10]
```

> {"zeresima", "prima", "seconda", "terza", "quarta", "quinta", 
> "sesta", "settima", "ottava", "nona", "decima"}

```
IntegerName[#, {"Italian", "Ordinal", "Masculine"}] & /@ Range[0, 10]
```

> {"zeresimo", "primo", "secondo", "terzo", "quarto", "quinto", 
> "sesto", "settimo", "ottavo", "nono", "decimo"}

---

For English, the usage is simpler.

```
IntegerName[#, "Ordinal"] & /@ Catenate[{Range[0, 20],
   Range[30, 100, 10]}]
```

> {"zeroth", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", 
> "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelfth", 
> "thirteenth", "fourteenth", "fifteenth", "sixteenth", "seventeenth", 
> "eighteenth", "nineteenth", "twentieth", "thirtieth", "fortieth", 
> "fiftieth", "sixtieth", "seventieth", "eightieth", "ninetieth", "one 
> hundredth"}

To use the shorter form such as `1st`, `2nd` etc., the last two letters can be extracted from the above using `StringTake`.

```
StringJoin @@@ ({IntegerString[#], 
     StringTake[IntegerName[#, "Ordinal"], -2]} & /@ Range[0, 100])
```

> {"0th", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", 
> "9th", "10th", "11th", "12th", "13th", "14th", "15th", "16th", 
> "17th", "18th", "19th", "20th", "21st", "22nd", "23rd", "24th", 
> "25th", "26th", "27th", "28th", "29th", "30th", "31st", "32nd", 
> "33rd", "34th", "35th", "36th", "37th", "38th", "39th", "40th", 
> "41st", "42nd", "43rd", "44th", "45th", "46th", "47th", "48th", 
> "49th", "50th", "51st", "52nd", "53rd", "54th", "55th", "56th", 
> "57th", "58th", "59th", "60th", "61st", "62nd", "63rd", "64th", 
> "65th", "66th", "67th", "68th", "69th", "70th", "71st", "72nd", 
> "73rd", "74th", "75th", "76th", "77th", "78th", "79th", "80th", 
> "81st", "82nd", "83rd", "84th", "85th", "86th", "87th", "88th", 
> "89th", "90th", "91st", "92nd", "93rd", "94th", "95th", "96th", 
> "97th", "98th", "99th", "100th"}

---

The resource function `OrdinalNumberString` from this [page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/OrdinalNumberString) is available, but using it hanged my system. I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64.

---