# Integer to ordinal number string (words only)

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion

I am trying to create a function that does:

```
f[1]
(* "first" *)

f[27]
(* "twentyseventh" *)

f[50]
(* "fiftieth *)
```

There need not be a hyphen or space in `"twentyseventh"`.

I searched [`"OrdinalNumber" (Interpreter type)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/OrdinalNumber.html), [`IntegerName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html), and [`SpokenString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpokenString.html), but none of these seem to generate actual ordinal numbers composed of words only.

Comment: I wrote a python script to do this. Right now it converts pretty large numbers but I want it to theoretically go up to infinity. Here's a link to the script on github: https://github.com/stephen-wolfe/python-scripts/blob/master/ordinalize.py

Answer (score 5):

[`IntegerName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html) as of Version 10 should fit the bill:

```
IntegerName[ 1, "Ordinal" ]
```

> first

```
IntegerName[#, "Ordinal" ]& /@ {27, 50}
```

> {"twenty-seventh", "fiftieth"}

It even produces word-only answers for longer ordinal numbers:

```
IntegerName[ 10000027, "Ordinal" ]
```

> "ten million twenty-seventh"

**Building a custom converter function (word-only) to OP's demands**

The OP wants to remove `Whitespace` and `-` from the ordinal string which can be done using `StringReplace` within a custom function:

```
f[ i_Integer ] := With[
    {
        ordinalStringRules = StringReplace[ Whitespace | "-" -> "" ]
    }
    ,
    IntegerName[ i, "Ordinal" ] // ordinalStringRules
]

f[ 10000027 ]
```

> "tenmilliontwentyseventh"

Comment: @JungHwan Does this answer your question?

Comment: For a different, maybe more general, take on this problem see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190568/764).